# Reading and appending info on one HTML file to another using JS

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have an HTML file `Planner.html` that contains an external JS script `PlannerScript.js`. I need another JS script `ParentScript.js` to access `Planner.html` and read and append info on it to another HTML file `ParentPortal.html`. Here is my code:

`Planner.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your Planner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>My Planner for today</h1>
      <h2>Homework</h2>
    <br>
<!-- these functions will ask user for input and append that input into the list. I need the user input in these lists to be appended on the other HTML file. -->
    <button onclick = "AddHome()">Add Entry</button>
      <br>
      <button onclick = "RemoveEntryHome()">Remove Homework Entry</button>
    <ul id = "entrieshome">
    </ul> 


    <h2>Tests</h2>
    <button onclick = "AddTest()">Add Entry</button>
      <br>
      <button onclick = "RemoveEntryTest()">Remove Test Entry</button>
    <ul id = "entriestest"> 
    </ul>

    <h2>Assignments/Schoolwork</h2>
    <button onclick = "AddSchool()">Add Entry</button>
      <br>
    <button onclick="RemoveEntrySchool()">Remove Schoolwork Entry</button>
    <ul id = "entriesschool">
    </ul>
     <br>
     <br>
     <button onclick="ApproveEntries()">Approve Entries</button>
    <script src="PlannerScript.js"></script>
    <script src="MonsterScript.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you have a question about this?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how to read a html file from a JS script and then append that info to another HTML file.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of web dev, your question is much more than you realize. The tech you're looking for is called [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX). Important note, this does require some sort of server, as it relies on http headers.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look. Thanks!